# 22.04 Doesn't Have permission to access files when boot

Tags: dual-boot, permissions

Yesterday I noticed that I was running out of space on my ubuntu partition. I have a dual boot. I cleared 30Gb from a simple storage partition and was trying to give it to the ubuntu one.

I noticed that i cannot do that and most probably I pressed the take ownership button from the Disks tool.

After that i noticed that the battery icon showed 0% and I tried a reboot.

And since then i was not able to access ubuntu.

I tried the recovery mode.
I tried boot-repair.
I cleaned around 10GB of space from that partition.
I tried to enable the failed service files that failed when I used systemctl status.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you did. Can you elaborate "I cleared 30Gb from a simple storage partition", "was trying to five it to the ubuntu one", "I pressed the take ownership button from the Disks tool"?

Comment: Most likely you removed something important from the system. The only feasible option would be to re-install.

Comment: Sure thing.  

I resized a partition where there is no OS, just simple storage. it's named D on my device. 

That 30GB was now names free space. 

After that I tried to resize the ubuntu partition. I noticed I cannot add more space to it and tried to gain permision to do so. One of the options was to take ownership of that partition. Which i think i did. 

after that I tried to reboot and it does not reboot anymore

Comment: What is "just simple storage"? 1) You can't resize partitions of a working system. 2) Changing ownership of system files ruins the system. Hence reinstall.

Comment: That will probably be the final solution. I was trying to see if i can gain access to the browser from ubuntu to backup some information. But i guess it is what it is.

Comment: You can boot from a LiveUSB and backup your files.